# Trigger my sql query onchange event of dropdown without page loading

Tags: php, javascript, highcharts

I have been trying to pull some information from the database and using them to generate highcharts and then show generated highcharts in certain divs on my page onchange event of the drop down. I cannot use ajax call as it doesnot support pulling highchart from another page (I already tried that).  I want to do 
Something like, I somehow get `$_POST['dropdown']` value then use that value to get output from sql queries and then pass those values to highcharts javascripting function to generate highcharts WITHOUT PAGE LOADING.

Its very easy to do if the page gets loaded as i can generate the result in the sequence mentioned above on behalf of `$_POST['dropdown']` value. Kindly Help.

Thanks,

Comment: what are the highcharts you cant pull with ajax?

Comment: there's a working example on the official site.

Comment: @MohdMoe kindly check http://www.highcharts.com/

Comment: @itachi not yet i am working on localhost at the moment...
Is there no way to stop loading of the page like return false in javascripting

Comment: i am not sure what you are asking here. can you show your codes?

Answer (score 0):

> I cannot use ajax call as it doesnot support pulling highchart from
>   another page (I already tried that)

Your only other option would be to load an iframe's src with JS. Why exactly can't you use Ajax?

Comment: i used it but it didnot return any chart but it returned textual data only